# How can I calculate a gradient using a Jeppesen Student Flight Computer?

Tags: flight-training

On a Jeppesen Student Flight Computer (CSG), how does one calculate the gradient in percentage if the ground distance and height above ground level are given?

I can't find anything in the [accompanying manual](https://e-atpl.com/pdf/Jeppesen_E6B_flight_computer_manual.pdf). Apparently this is possible on the E6B and CRP-5.

Comment: Can you provide a sample problem?

Comment: I figured it out. It works the same way as with the CRP-5. If for example the ground distance and height above ground level is given, then one aligns the ground distance on the inner scale (the B scale) with the height above ground level on the outer scale (A scale). Then look up the number 10 or 10 mark on the inner scale (the CRP-5 has an additional red arrow for this mark), and read the gradient in percentage on the outer scale.

Comment: Instead of commenting, you should post this as an answer on your own question to help anyone who finds it in the future. Comments are liable to be deleted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works the same way as with the CRP-5. If for example the ground distance and height above ground level is given, then one aligns the ground distance on the inner scale (the B scale) with the height above ground level on the outer scale (A scale). Then look up the number 10 or 10 mark on the inner scale (the CRP-5 has an additional red arrow for this mark), and read the gradient in percentage on the outer scale.